# Render samer result using DOM API as document.write?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this function:

```
  function getScript(src) {
    document.write('<' + 'script src="' + src + '"' +
                   ' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');
  }
```

Due to constrains, I can't use document.write. not supported in xhtml(implemented in firefox). Is there some other way to write it? For example using "DOM API"? I use jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get/execute a script, use [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), like this:

```
$.getScript(src);
```

..really just replace your `getScript()` calls with [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) and do away with the function.  What this does is call [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with a `dataType` of `"script"`, [which creates a `<script>` element and appends it to the `<head>`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L294-329), similar to what your code in the question is trying to do writing it in the document.